# Retrieve data by value in JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to search into a JSON file for a **value** and return a different value from the same object.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
   "source": {
       "name": "source1", 
        "url": "https://someurl",
        "apiKey": "someapi"

   },
   "targets" : [
       {
          "name" : "target1",
          "url": "https://target1url",
          "apiKey": "target1api"

       },
       {
          "name" : "target2",
          "url": "https://target2url",
          "apiKey": "target2api"
       }
   ]
}
```

I want to retrieve the "apiKey" value by searching by name. I understand that this can be done with `foreach()` and `if` statements, but I just can't get the value. My PHP code is this:

```
// get the json config file 
$json = file_get_contents('config.json'); 

// decode the JSON 
$config = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($config["targets"] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->name == "target1") {
        echo $value->apiKey;
    }
}
```

Is it bad practice to have the "name" at the same level as the other attributes? For example, should the "name" be the parent name and the other values its children? Or, if the JSON is OK, can you help me understand why the above doesn't work?

Comment: sorry forgot the $config declaration- //get the json config file
$json = file_get_contents('config.json');
// decode the JSON
$config = json_decode($json, true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your data structure.

The reason your code is not working is that you have converted the structure to an array using `TRUE` as the second param for `json_decode($json, true);` but you are still addressing the resulting data structure as an object. Just remove the `TRUE` parameter and the resulting PHP data will remain as an object, like this

```
$f = file_get_contents('tst.json');

$json = json_decode($f);
//print_r($json);
foreach ($json->targets as $obj){
    if ( $obj->name == 'target1') {
        echo $obj->apiKey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's non-object, it's array. Rewrite you loop.

```
foreach ($config["targets"] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['name'] == "target1") {
        echo $value['apiKey'];
    }
}
```